# LOOKUP function not giving expected results

Tags: excel, lookup

I am having a problem with the `LOOKUP` function.

To test some things, I entered the following function

```
=LOOKUP(4.19, $B$2:$B$6, $C$2:$C$6)
```

And on every line, it gives me a different answer. I don't know what is the problem with it because it just gives me the wrong answer. It should say "blue".

[image: Example given]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup value must be (always) in the first column of the lookup table. So, if you are looking for `4.19` (which is in the right-most-column) in order to return a value from a column further to the left then you'll have to change to `INDEX/MATCH` like so:

```
=Index($C$2:$C$6,Match(4.19, $B$2:$B$6,0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly!
I am still new to excel so help is greatly appriciated

Comment: So is verbal thanks a bad thing? I mean I intended on doing both

Comment: I got another question if I may!
After using said formula and getting the value I would like to dispose of one of the tables but have the sheet keep the values. How do I make the function not need a ref and just stay as the value it was in?

Comment: @Noob_Programmer Is this what you mean? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-a-formula-with-its-result-38001951-c0e8-4fbd-9048-37ef81e2891e

Answer (score 1):

With [`LOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) the values you are searching in must be in descending order. If you want to keep the order as is, you might want to use [`INDEX/MATCH` functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/181212/how-to-use-the-lookup-function-with-unsorted-data-in-excel).

Answer (score 0):

With the third argument you tell the function what the output should be if the first argument( 4.19) is valid. since you enterd a range of cells, the output differs. Also if you are searching for an exact value you should add a further argument at the end of the function 
=VLOOKUP(4.19, $B$2:$B$6, D1, FALSE)